# Getting "Cypress could not detect tests in this file." error message in cypress test runner

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

**I got this error message in Test runner.**

[image]

And my feature file:
[image]

Can anyone provide a solution for this issue. I tried with multiple solution but nothing helped.

**cypress.config.js** file content

```html
   var config = {
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  video: false,
  retries: {
    runMode: 2,
    openMode: 0,
  },
};
config.e2e = {
  baseUrl: 'https://www.redbus.in/',
  specPattern: 'cypress/integration/features/**/*.{feature,js}',
  supportFile: 'cypress/support/index.js',
  setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
    // Pre-process cucumber .feature files
    const options = {
      ...browserify.defaultOptions,
      typescript: resolve.sync('typescript', { baseDir: config.projectRoot }),
    };
```

Comment: Hello, can't test it right now but are you sure that  specPattern is valid?

Comment: Yes previously I was able to run the script with the same specPattern. The change what I made was renaming the folder name which contains the feature file like "cypress/integration/features/app-angular/search.feature" to "cypress/integration/features/hsk/search.feature". In the entire project I renamed the app-angular to hsk.

Comment: @ParamaSivam Did you solve this issue? I got the same issue today after moving my Test Component file from the App src folder to my Cypress component folder

Comment: @DericLima No I couldnt able to fix this issue so I created a new project and this time I tried with normal cypress not with BDD framework so now it is working fine for me.